# Correct format for input data on CloudML

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to send a job up to my object detection model on CloudML to get predictions. I'm following the guide at https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/online-predict but I'm getting an error when submitting the request:

RuntimeError: Prediction failed: Error processing input: Expected uint8, got '\xf6>\x00\x01\x04\xa4d\x94...(more bytes)...\x00\x10\x10\x10\x04\x80\xd9' of type 'str' instead.

This is my code:

```
img = base64.b64encode(open("file.jpg", "rb").read()).decode('utf-8')
json = {"b64": img}
result = predict_json(project, model, json, "v1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault, I forgot to add `--input_type encoded_image_string_tensor` when I exported the graph.

Comment: I overlooked this one too. Thanks so much!